# How to set up Vary HTTP header in Symfony2 web app?

Tags: symfony, http-headers, user-agent, vary

In my Symfony2 web app, I need to set up Vary HTTP header for User-Agent, like in this link,

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/details?hl=en

Does any know how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `@Cache` annotation, or you can set headers directly on a `Response` object.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/cache.html

Comment: thanks a lot. i solved it like you suggested. Used @Cache(vary="User-Agent") before each class